# DetailsView Trouble Retrieving Values

Tags: asp.net

The purpose of my detailsview is to collect report parameters for the user to enter when running a report. So I build the details view dynamically because report parameters are data driven, stored in the database per the report.
The object being bound to is created by reflection dynamically at run-time from the report parameters, with one property per each parameter, so it contains simple date or collection properties, which I turn into a combo box or date box dynamically by creating templates dynamically.

In the item_updating event, I simply want to get the values the user entered so I know how to run the report.
I looked in all the properties of e and also tried findcontrol to get to the values the user entered. both e and findcontrol are empty. This is how I got data back in the past so I don't know why they aren't there. It almost as if the controls themselves are not represented in the object model of the detailsview at that time.

```
  <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="false" DefaultMode="Edit" >
    <Fields>
      <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" UpdateText="Run" ShowCancelButton="false" ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Fields>
  </asp:DetailsView>
```

code behind

```vb
  Private Sub BuildDetailView(DataSource As Object)


    Dim Properties() As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = DataSource.GetType.GetProperties
    Dim Template As System.Web.UI.ITemplate
    For Each PropertyInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In Properties
      Template = Nothing
      If PropertyInfo.PropertyType Is GetType(System.DateTime) Then
        Template = New DateTemplate(DataSource, PropertyInfo)
      ElseIf GetType(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(PropertyInfo.PropertyType) Then
        Template = New ListTemplate(DataSource, PropertyInfo, Report.InputReportParameters(Array.IndexOf(Properties, PropertyInfo)).Enumeration.MultiSelect)
      End If
      If Template IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim TemplateField As New TemplateField
        TemplateField.HeaderText = PropertyInfo.Name
        TemplateField.ItemTemplate = Template
        DetailsView1.Fields.Add(TemplateField)
      End If
    Next
  End Sub

  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CheckAuthentication()

    BuildDetailView(Report.ReportParametersDataObject)

    If Report.ReportParameters.Any AndAlso Not Report.InputReportParameters.Any Then
      Run() 'no parameters are for data entry

    ElseIf Not IsPostBack Then
      lblReportType.Text = String.Format("Report {0}", Report.Type)
      DetailsView1.DataSource = New List(Of Object) From {Report.ReportParametersDataObject}
      DetailsView1.DataBind()
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Sub DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemUpdating
    Run(e.NewValues)
  End Sub
```

List Template helper:

```vb
Public Class ListTemplate
  Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate

  Public Sub New(DataSource As Object, PropertyInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo, Multiselect As Boolean)
    Me.DataSource = DataSource
    Me.PropertyInfo = PropertyInfo
    Me.Multiselect = Multiselect
  End Sub

  Private DataSource As Object
  Private Multiselect As Boolean
  Private PropertyInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo

  Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As System.Web.UI.Control) Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn
    Dim ListBox As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox
    ListBox.DataSource = PropertyInfo.GetValue(DataSource, Nothing)
    ListBox.DataTextField = "Text"
    ListBox.DataValueField = "Value"
    ListBox.SelectionMode = IIf(Multiselect, ListSelectionMode.Multiple, ListSelectionMode.Single)
    ListBox.Rows = Math.Min(25, ListBox.DataSource.count)
    ListBox.EnableViewState = True
    container.Controls.Add(ListBox)
  End Sub
End Class
```

DateTemplate Helper:

```vb
Public Class DateTemplate
  Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate

  Public Sub New(DataSource As Object, PropertyInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)
    Me.DataSource = DataSource
    Me.PropertyInfo = PropertyInfo
  End Sub

  Private DataSource As Object
  Private PropertyInfo As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo

  Public Sub InstantiateIn(container As System.Web.UI.Control) Implements System.Web.UI.ITemplate.InstantiateIn
    Dim Textbox As New System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    Textbox.ID = PropertyInfo.Name.Replace(" ", String.Empty)
    Textbox.EnableViewState = True
    Dim CalendarExtender As New AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender
    CalendarExtender.TargetControlID = Textbox.ID
    CalendarExtender.SelectedDate = PropertyInfo.GetValue(DataSource, Nothing)
    CalendarExtender.DefaultView = AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarDefaultView.Months
    CalendarExtender.Format = "MMMM yyyy"
    container.Controls.Add(Textbox)
    container.Controls.Add(CalendarExtender)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absense of any answers or even comments, I worked around this issue by creating my own asp.net custom control.

The way it works is very simple. It has a DataSource property and it creates the UI adding an edit widget for each property. According to the propertyinfo.propertytype, it creates an editor for that type.

Once the user submits changes it raises a server-side event handing back the datasource object containing the changed values.

It's so simple, even I can understand how to use it.